# Caffe: Print the softmax score

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

In the given example of MNIST in the Caffe installation.

For any given test image, how to get the softmax scores for each category and do some processing on them? Say compute the mean and variance of them.

I am newbie so a detail would help me a lot. I am able to train the model and use the testing feature to get the prediction but I am not sure which files are to be edited in order to get the above results.

Comment: how are your python skills?

Comment: I would say at least undergrad level.

Comment: then use Python interface with deploy.prototxt and you can do whatever you want with the outputs

Comment: @Shai Can you point to any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python interface

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/deploy.prototxt', '/path/to/weights.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
in_ = read_data(...) # this is up to you to read a sample and convert it to numpy array
out_ = net.forward(data=in_) # assuming your net expects "data" in blob
```

Now you have the output of your net in a dictionary `out` (keys are names of output blobs). You can run it in a loop on several examples etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer your question. Assuming in your deploying net, the softmax layer is like below:

```
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type : "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "prob"
}
```

In your python code that processes data, combining with the code @Shai provided, you can get the probability of each category by adding code based on @Shai's code:

```
predicted_prob = net.blobs['prob'].data
```

predicted_prob will be returned an array that contains the probabilities with all categories.

For example, if you only have two categories, `predicted_prob[0][0]` will be the probability that this testing data belongs to one category and `predicted_prob[0][1]` will be the probability of the other one.

PS:

If you don't want to write any additional python script, according to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist 
it says this example will automatically do the testing every 500 iterations. "500" is defined in solver, such as https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt

So you need to trace back the caffe source code that processes the solver file. I guess it should be https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp

I am not sure solver.cpp is the correct file you need to look at. But in this file, you can see it has functions of testing and calculation of some values. I hope it can give you some ideas if no one else can answer your question.